# Как сделать эффект тиснения на CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Текст в Photoshop сделан с эффектом тиснения, как это сделать на CSS?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, такое лучше просто сохранить из этого самого фотошопа и картинкой воткнуть на сайт

Answer (score 2):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sacramento');
body {
  background:#ccc;
}
h2 {
  font:200px 'Sacramento', cursive;
  font-style: italic; 
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #565656;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(210,193,163,1), 0px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .18);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -moz-background-clip: text;
          background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<h2>Lorem</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sacramento');
body {
  font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
  font-size: 800%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: yellow;
  font-style: italic;
  text-shadow: 7px 7px 2px grey;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum
```

upd. Погуглил что такое тиснение:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Leckerli+One');
body {
  font-family: 'Leckerli One', cursive;
  font-size: 600%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #aaa;
  font-style: italic;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum
```

Comment: `Тиснение !== Тень`

Comment: Спасибо за подходящий шрифт Sacramento, но здесь только тень сделана...

Comment: Я не вижу что имеется в виду под тиснением?

Comment: Скрин из Photoshop http://prntscr.com/hrsyil

Comment: Ничего не говорит. Я не дизайнер.

Answer (score 0):

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sacramento');

body {
  background:#ccc;
}

h2 {
  font:200px 'Sacramento', cursive;
  font-style: italic; 
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #565656;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), -1px -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8), 1px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}


<h2>Lorem</h2>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allura');
body {
  font-family: 'Allura', cursive;
  background-color: #474747;
}
h1{
  font-size: 200px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  color: #c7b79b;
  text-shadow: 0px 10px 1px #3e3e3e;
}
```

```html
<h1>Rome</h1>
```

Изначально я думал что в данном шрифте необходимо сдвинуть letter-spacing в отрицательную сторону, чтобы получить эффект тиснения, но найдя данный шрифт я понял что это вовсе не нужно.

Непонятен тогда вопрос автора, эффект тиснения подразумевает тиснения самих букв или же эффект наложения на сам текст? Что именно вы хотели, пока-что совсем не понятна суть вопроса.